# Text-indent after image

Tags: css, indentation, text-indent

I am trying to indent text wrapped in a `<span>` tag.
 **The first line is moved to the right** because of an image and I would like the **following lines to start with the same indentation as the first** one.
Here is the fiddle, illustrating my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/scoa8npd/

And here is my simple code:
**HTML**

```
<img src="https://schwesidesign.com/active.gif" class="cross" /><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.cross { padding-right: 5px; }

span {
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-indent: -10px;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current markup is not important (`image`+`span`) then you can use a `<ul>` with custom `list-style-image`.

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url('https://schwesidesign.com/active.gif');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/scoa8npd/1/

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so so much!!

Answer (score 2):

You can make the `span` an `inline-block` then the `margin-left` will move all the lines correctly.

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/wcfphxqz/1/)**

Code:

```
span {
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    vertical-align: top;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! phts answer was fast and simpler but your answer would work as well!

Answer (score 1):

use `float:left` and `margin-bottom` to cross div:

```
.cross {
    padding-right: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! phts answer was fast and simpler but your answer would work as well!